# What is the output of predict.coxph() using type = "survival"?

Tags: survival-analysis, cox-regression, survival, cox

I am trying to learn what the various outputs of predict.coxph() mean. I am currently attempting to fit a cox model on a training set then use the resulting coefficients from the training set to make predictions in a test set (new set of data).

I see from the predict.coxph() help page that I could use `type = "survival"` to extract and individual's survival probability-- which is equal to exp(-expected).

Here is a code block of what I have attempted so far, using the ISLR2 BrainCancer data.

```html
set.seed(123)
n.training = round(nrow(BrainCancer) * 0.70) # 70:30 split
idx = sample(1:nrow(BrainCancer), size = n.training)
d.training = BrainCancer[idx, ]
d.test = BrainCancer[-idx, ]

# fit a model using the training set
fit = coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ sex + diagnosis + loc + ki + gtv + stereo, data = d.training)

# get predicted survival probabilities for the test set
pred = predict(fit, type = "survival", newdata = d.test)
```

The predictions generated:
predict(fit, type = "survival", newdata = d.test)

[1] 0.9828659 0.8381164 0.9564982 0.2271862 0.2883800 0.9883625 0.9480138 0.9917512 1.0000000 0.9974775 0.7703657 0.9252100 0.9975044 0.9326234 0.8718161 0.9850815 0.9545622 0.4381646 0.8236644

[20] 0.2455676 0.7289031 0.9063336 0.9126897 0.9988625 0.4399697 0.9360874

Are these survival probabilities associated with a specific time point? From the help page, it sounds like these are survival probabilities at the follow-up times in the `newdata` argument. Is this correct?

Additional questions:

- How is the baseline hazard estimated in predict.coxph? Is it using the Breslow estimator?
- If `type = "expected"` is used, are these values the cumulative hazard? If yes, what are the relevant time points for these?

Thank you!